# How secure and portable are Cryptkeeper encrypted folders?

Tags: password, encryption

I have some questions about `Cryptkeeper`.

1. Is it safe to use `Cryptkeeper` for password protecting folders in
   ubuntu?Is there a chance that using Cryptkeeper causes data loss?(in
   cases other than loosing your password)
2. what happens to encrypted folders when `Cryptkeeper` is uninstalled?
3. Are encrypted folders just encrypted in Linux distros or are they encrypted on Windows operating systems too?

Comment: It would appear that the answers to the first question should revised thusly: 1. It's safe to use Cryptkeeper in that it does not cause no data loss, but it conversely affords no protection. This is due to the answer to the second part of this question, in that the encrypted password is always `p`, regardless of what the user enters. Reference: [Debian bug #852751](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852751)

Comment: Relevant bug report: [\[cryptkeeper\] Sets the same password "p" for everything independently of user input](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=852751)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the 1st question: How secure the data is largely depends on the user. EncFS works with a private and public folder where the public folder is the encrypted version that can be used to upload to an on-line service or across machines. If for example you place an unencrypted file inside the public folder it will be shared making the contents visible to anyone.

If you log in the private folder will not be mounted. A user that would assume something is broken and starts messing with it, instead of just mounting the private folder will loose data. Mind though that "user" here might not be "you".

> Is there a chance that using Cryptkeeper causes data loss?

Here you are probably misunderstanding and also as an answer to your 2nd question: Cryptkeeper is a tool to make it easier to mount/unmount encypted folders. It has nothing to do with the actual encryption. That is done with EncFS.

Question 3 is off topic but as a general answer: EncFS is not Ubuntu specific and can be used on all Linux systems. It will act the same on all those systems; only the method of installation will differ (rpm, yast instead of apt-get). Regarding Windows: there is an *experimental* implementation of EncFS call [EncFSWin](http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html). To me an indication to stay away from it unless you make sure to keep the originals away from it (if "experimental" means you someday face an unrecoverable bug you still have the originals).